# Datastax Enterprise 5.0.1 Opscenter 6.0.1 returns 400 error when retrieving metrics by API

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm using Opscenter 6.0.1 to monitor DSE 5.0.1.
I am testing Opscenter APIs to retrieve node/cluster metrics but I get
400 errors when I throw queries as like below.

```
curl -vvv -H 'opscenter-session: xxxxxx' -G
'http://<opscenter>/<cluster>/metrics/<node>/data-load'

> GET /IDC/metrics/<node>/data-load HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: <opscenter>
> Accept: */*
> opscenter-session: xxxxxx
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 19 Aug 2016 20:45:36 GMT
* Server TwistedWeb/15.3.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: TwistedWeb/15.3.0
< Content-Type: application/json
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
<
* Connection #0 to host <opscenter> left intact
{"message": "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and
'NoneType'", "type": "TypeError"}
```

I could use the same session id, opscenter ip, node ip for different
API call(APIs to retrieve the configurations) and I got responses with no problem but no luck with any of
metrics related calls.
The error message seems complaining about "-" but I am not sure what
is wrong with the data I called for..

I am just trying some calls described here without using any optional query
parameters: http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/api/docs/metrics.html

Where should I change to retrieve the metrics?

Thanks,
Aoi

Answer (score 1):

This is a recent known bug in OpsCenter 6.0.1 (tracked internally in JIRA as OPSC-9727). We plan to include the fix in 6.0.3 patch release.

The workaround is to include values for the `start` and `end` params. As you noted, those params are supposed to be optional, but excluding them results in this bug. You can mimic the default behavior by specifying the default values, [as documented here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.0/api/docs/metrics.html#filtering-metric-output), which are:

- `end` - a timestamp, in seconds, indicating the current time
- `start` - a timestamp, in seconds, indicating one day before `end`

We apologize, and those responsible have been heckled without mercy.

Comment: Thank you Scott for the information. I'll use the workaround until we upgrade!

Comment: Hi Scott, I tried your workaround but still cannot make it work. # curl -H 'opscenter-session: xxxx' -X GET http://<IP>/<cluster>/new-metrics -d "metrics=heap-used" -d "nodes=<IP>" -d 'start=1473186039' -d 'end=1473272439'  -d 'function=average' -d 'step=120'
{"message": "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'", "type": "TypeError"}

Comment: # date +%s
1473272439  
I get the date in seconds from this command result and calculated start date from this numbers

Comment: Sorry @aoi - I will try to troubleshoot this week. Are you still seeing this problem?

Comment: Yes, still cannot make it work...appreciate your help, Scott.